# Create A Folder Programmatically In Xcode - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following line of code to save my file of yoyo.txt in the Documents folder ::

```
NSString *docDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSLog(@"docDir is yoyo :: %@", docDir);
NSString *FilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yoyo.txt"];
```

However, I wish to save my file in a folder of yoyo i.e. inside the Documents folder i.e. I want to create another folder named as "yoyo" and then save my file of yoyo.txt into it. How can I do that ?? Thanks.

Comment: Xcode is the IDE. The language is Objective C, you can write the same code in an text editor and compile it on the command line. It's a common mistake though, to mix up `Xcode` and `Objective C`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a sample code (assume `manager` is `[NSFileManager defaultManager]`):

```
BOOL isDirectory;
NSString *yoyoDir = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yoyo"];
if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:yoyoDir isDirectory:&isDirectory] || !isDirectory) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete
                                                         forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:yoyoDir
           withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                            attributes:attr
                                 error:&error];
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error creating directory path: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: what is "isDictionary" in your code. Also what is the purpose of NSDictionary which you have declared in your code ??

Comment: isDictionary is BOOL, used to check if the file that exists in the path is directory, because there could be a file which is not a directory... The dictionary is used to pass attributes for the newly created directory in the code I have posted this is `The file is stored in an encrypted format on disk and cannot be read from or written to while the device is locked or booting.` you can pass `nil` to this. You may also see [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 11):

```
+(void)createDirForImage :(NSString *)dirName
{
    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dirName];
    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])    //Does directory already exist?
    {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path
                                       withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                        attributes:nil
                                                             error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here dataPath  will be the final path for saving your file

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/yoyo"];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
    }
    dataPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/yoyo.txt"];
```